# Unable to create MySQL table: Errorcode 1005

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

Could you please help me figure this out

When I'm trying to create the table dvdTitle I'm getting below error

> Error Code: 1005
>
> Can't create table 'netflixclone.dvdtitle' (errno: 150)

Here is the code. Not sure what's going wrong

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `netflixclone`.`person` (
  `personID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `personFirstName` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  `personLastName` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  `actor` TINYINT(1)  NULL ,
  `producer` TINYINT(1)  NULL ,
  `director` TINYINT(1)  NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`personID`) );

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `netflixclone`.`dvdTitle` (
  `dvdID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `dvdMPPARating` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `dvdProducer` INT NOT NULL,
  `dvdDirector` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dvdID`) ,
   CONSTRAINT `personID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dvdProducer` , `dvdDirector` )
    REFERENCES `netflixclone`.`person` (`personID` , `personID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: I don't think you can reference the same column twice in your `REFERENCES` clause, but maybe someone can verify this.

Comment: Yup. You are right Ed. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the 'netflixclone.dvdtitle' table with default charset as utf8.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `netflixclone`.`dvdTitle` (
  `dvdID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `dvdMPPARating` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `dvdProducer` INT NOT NULL,
  `dvdDirector` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dvdID`) ,
   CONSTRAINT `personID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dvdProducer` , `dvdDirector` )
    REFERENCES `netflixclone`.`person` (`personID` , `personID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constraint is weird.  I think you want two constraints here.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `netflixclone`.`dvdTitle` (
  `dvdID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `dvdMPPARating` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `dvdProducer` INT NOT NULL,
  `dvdDirector` INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`dvdID`) ,
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`dvdProducer`) REFERENCES `netflixclone`.`person`
       ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION),
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`dvdDirector`) REFERENCES `netflixclone`.`person`
       ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
);
```

Comment: I think you are right. The constraint is weird. I can refer the same foreign key for two of my columns. In that case why do I even need two columns. I misunderstood the requirements. Thanks for pointing that it's weird. Else I wouldn't have given a thought :)

Comment: @user2225994 . . . You need two columns because a DVD has a producer and a director, and these are different people.  It is perfectly normal to have multiple foreign keys, even referring to the same table.

Answer (score 0):

`FOREIGN KEY (dvdProducer)
    REFERENCES netflixclone.person (personID )`
you can try this